# What's the accepted way to distribute an Excel template with .NET dependencies?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vba, excel-2013

I've created a handy-dandy excel template for myself that other people want it now as well. It has VBA and a couple of dependencies in the form of .NET /C# libraries that I've built.  For the template to work on another machine, currently I have to drop down to an administrator command window, `regasm` all the libraries and then the template will work.

So is there a better way to distribute a template that doesn't require all this manual work?  For instance, Excel embeds VBA - can it also somehow embed C# code?

Answer (score 1):

You could create some  `Install` batch file (or other kinds) to do those `regasm` things for you.